# Installed Pandas 2.0.0 in conda environment but spyder still shows and uses old pandas version

Tags: python, pandas, miniconda

I just installed the latest pandas package 2.0.0 by `conda install pandas`. I checked the package by `conda list` which showed `2.0.0`.

However, when I opened Spyder and did

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
```

It printed out `1.3.4`.

I tried to remove `pandas` by `conda remove pandas`. However, the package still loads in Spyder when I did `import pandas as pd`.

How can I resolve this issue and make spyder use the pandas 2.0.0 that i installed? This is jus so frustrating.

Comment: You are probably `conda install`'ing to a different environment than what your spider kernel is using. What is printed when you do `import sys;print(sys.executable)` in spyder?